# Update a column a if null else update column b else if both column's are not null do nothing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

This is my table:
called **room**

```
+---------+---------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
| room_id | room_no | room_stat | room_name   | player_a_id | player_b_id | turn_of |
+---------+---------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
|       1 |       1 |         0 | blah        |           0 |           0 |       0 |
|       2 |       5 |         0 | second room |           0 |           0 |       0 |
|       3 |       3 |         0 | 3rd room    |           0 |           0 |       0 |
|       4 |       4 |         0 | 4th room    |           0 |           0 |       0 |
+---------+---------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+

$player_id //contains the id of the player who wants to join
```

**#room table:**

1. if player_a_id !null  and player_b_id !null then update nothing; if
2. player_a_id = null and player_b_id !null then update room set
3. player_a_id = $player_id; if player_b_id = null and player_a_id !null then update room set player_b_id = $player_id;

*my current query(thanks JW)(i tried to edit it but to no avail i failed).*

```
     UPDATE  room
             SET     player_a_id = IF(player_a_id IS NULL OR player_a_id  = 0 AND player_b_id != :chara_id, :chara_id, player_a_id),
                     player_b_id = IF(player_a_id != :chara_id AND player_b_id IS NOT NULL, :chara_id, player_b_id)
             WHERE   room_id  = :room_id
```

this is good but it updates the two columns if both are empty or = 0; which i only want to update 1.

**edit:**

here is sample result:
after player_id 1 joins room_id 4:

```
+---------+---------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
| room_id | room_no | room_stat | room_name   | player_a_id | player_b_id | turn_of |
+---------+---------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
|       1 |       1 |         0 | blah        |           0 |           0 |       0 |
|       2 |       5 |         0 | second room |           0 |           0 |       0 |
|       3 |       3 |         0 | 3rd room    |           0 |           0 |       0 |
|       4 |       4 |         0 | 4th room    |           1 |           1 |       0 |
+---------+---------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
```

since both columns are null then it updates both of the column i only want to update 1 column.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and results?  That will help clarify your rules.

Comment: Given your edits, which player do you update if they are both 0 (both empty)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reviewing your logic, you want to update player_a_id to $player_id *IF* player_a_id = 0 and player_b_id does not = 0.

And you want to update player_b_id to $player_id *IF* player_b_id = 0 and player_a_id is not = 0.

*EDIT* -- You also want to update player_a_id if they are both equal to 0.

```
UPDATE  room
SET     player_a_id = IF(player_a_id=0, :player_id, player_a_id),
    player_b_id = IF(player_a_id!=0 AND player_b_id=0, :player_id, player_b_id)
WHERE   room_id  = :room_id
```

Comment: @sgeddess yes, but then again the twist is that when both player_a_id and player_b_id are null then i want to insert player_id on player_a_id, your query will work but then again it will only work if 1 player is already in a room. i will really appriciate it if you help me with this.

Comment: @Viscocent -- why not change the first IF statement to just player_a_id=0 -- that should cover both cases?

Comment: i already got it. just added this condition on if#1 `player_b_id != :chara_id`, and if#2 `player_a_id != :chara_id`

Comment: thanks btw, i got the logic work when you replaced those IF NULL statements with 0's.

Comment: @Viscocent -- np, glad we could figure it out together!  Best regards.